# Ember.js - How to handle URL parameters when location history is enabled?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pushstate, ember-router

I'm migrating Ember.js app from `location` `hash` to `history`, in several places I use `?some-parameter=awesome` in the URL.

When `history` is enabled Ember simply removes all parameters from the URL, for example when you navigate to `/some-route?some-param` Ember will remove `?some-param` from the browser URL!

How to solve this issue and why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those query params aren't specified on the route, Ember won't build up the url using them.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/